# Help me drive Zmodem over ssh with expect

Tags: scripting, ssh, interactive, expect, zmodem

There's a nifty little tool called
[zssh](http://zssh.sourceforge.net/) that makes it easy to use the
`lszrz` utilities to transfer files using
[zmodem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM)
over an existing ssh
connection.  It's surprisingly convenient...but it seems like I ought
to be able to accomplish the same thing using `expect`.  I've gotten
this far...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh $argv
set ssh_spawn_id $spawn_id
send_user "ssh is: $ssh_spawn_id\n"

interact -o "\030B0000" {
    send_user "\nStarting zmodem receive.\n"

    spawn rz -v
    set rz_spawn_id $spawn_id
    send_user "rz is: $rz_spawn_id\n"

    while {1} {
        expect {
            eof break

            -i $rz_spawn_id -re .+ {
                send -raw -i $ssh_spawn_id $expect_out(buffer)
            }
            -i $ssh_spawn_id -re .+ {
                send -raw -i $rz_spawn_id $expect_out(buffer)
            }
        }
    }

    send_user "\nFinished zmodem receive.\n"
    set spawn_id $ssh_spawn_id
}
```

This start up `rz` after seeing a `ZRQINIT` frame, and it apparently connects
`rz` to the ssh session, but it doesn't work.  `rz` says:

```
Retry 0: Bad CRCe.**B0100000023be50
Retry 0: Bad CRC**B0600000023d984
Retry 0: Bad CRC**B0600000023d984
```

...and so forth.

Is there a way to make this work?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, if you're already using ssh, why not file transfer with scp?

Comment: Mostly (a) I'm just interested in trying to understand expect better, and (b) using scp requires a second connection, which may or may not be easy (for example, if there multiple hops in between my desktop and the remote system, being able to transfer files over the *existing* channel is tremendously convenient).

Comment: Hi Iarsks, have you solved this problem yet? I'd appreciate if you share any progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. using `exp_internal 1` while debugging is extremely useful. You're able to view how expect is matching the incoming text.
2. I wonder if the terminal is getting in the way. Before spawning `rz`, try `stty raw`. Then after `send_user "Finished..."` do `stty -raw`.
3. You can use `exp_continue` instead of a `while` loop:

   ```
   spawn rz -v
   set rz_spawn_id $spawn_id
   send_user "rz is: $rz_spawn_id\n"

   expect {
       -i $rz_spawn_id -re .+ {
           send -raw -i $ssh_spawn_id $expect_out(buffer)
           exp_continue
       }
       -i $ssh_spawn_id -re .+ {
           send -raw -i $rz_spawn_id $expect_out(buffer)
           exp_continue
       }
       eof
   }
   ```

   This doesn't have anything to do with the problem, just a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I believe that when using `interact`, everything is operating in `raw` mode by default...in any case, I added the explicit calls to `stty` and that doesn't seem to have changed the behavior.  Setting `exp_internal 1` certainly provides some additional diagnostics; I'll have to look at them more closely to see if I can tell exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that using `-e` / `--escape` (escape all control characters) option on sender side helps with some problems initiating the zmodem connection.

for example:

sending file:

```
sz -e somefile.ext
```

receiving file:

```
rz -e
```

This is handy for transfering files over IPMI sol (serial-over-lan) link.

There is [iterm2-zmodem](https://github.com/mmastrac/iterm2-zmodem) on OSX and Konsole on Linux with Zmodem integration.